# appending to links with jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, permalinks

I need to append an associate ID to the end of all links that go to a certain URL.

Here is what I have but I can't get it to work.

(this will be in WordPress)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("a[href*=doitbest]").click(function() {
     this.append("?memberid=5705&associate=true");
   });
 });
</script>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your selector (`a[href*=doitbest]`) works, you could try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("a[href*=doitbest]").click(function() {
      href = $(this).attr('href');
      del = href.indexOf('?') > -1 ? '&' : '?';
      href += del + 'memberid=5705&associate=true';
      $(this).attr('href', href);
   });
});
```

This changes the `href` attribute, not the link text. I'm not entirely sure that this is what you want, though. The `del` variable is used to append the URL part by means of the `&` or `?` char.

Comment: This didn't work, but I forgot to mention that the links I'm trying to append to are coming from an RSS feed that I'm displaying to the screen. Does this make a difference?

Comment: @Adam Munns Could be - if the links are not part of the DOM when the click handler is attached, no `href`'s are getting manipulated. Please post more code or a link to a live demo. Also, try to put a simple `alert()` inside the `click` function in order to see whether the handler is attached properly.

Comment: How can I tell if the parsed RSS feed is part of the DOM? The alert didn't appear to do anything.

Comment: What code would you need to see? I'll try and get a live version up in the meantime

Comment: Hey everybody I decided to use PHP to modify the feed instead.

Answer (score 1):

First, I believe you have to use `$(this)` instead of `this`.

You also wish to change the URL of the link. The change should be made to href attribute, so

```
 $('a#my_link').click( function (event) {
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '&id=1');
});
```